# How to optimize for core web vitals google page speed insights Avoid chaining critical requests issue?

Tags: cloudflare, google-pagespeed, core-web-vitals

Google page speed is showing to avoid critical requests for cloud flare javascript files.

[image]
I tried multiple methods such as preload, fetch the javascript files in the head section of the website. Not a single method was helpful for me. Even I tried to get in touch with Cloudflare,they weren't helping much.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me regarding this critical issue.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This link explains how to get Rocket Loader to ignore certain scripts:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436-How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-specific-JavaScripts-

Presumably, if Rocket Loader ignores them, the scripts will be loaded directly, and this will shorten the request chain.

Comment: Didn't help at all.